# Basic Single Producer, Single Consumer Queue. Memory not freed

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to implement a basic single producer, single consumer WorkerQueue. The problem is, that the memory of the queued objects is not freed.

If I

1. fill WorkerQueue::queue_ with 1000 objects of 1MB size
2. call WorkerQueue::Start()

the  memory usage of the application slowly winds down from 1GB to zero.

If I

1. call WorkerQueue::Start();
2. fill WorkerQueue::queue_ with 1000 objects of 1MB size

the memory usage of the application stays constant at 1GB until the programs exits.

In both cases all packets are processed and the packets destructor is called 1000 times. So despite Packet's destructor call, the memory does not seem to be freed. Of course I want to be able to enqueue items after ::Start() was called.

Platform: Ubuntu 18.10, g++-8

`g++  -pthread -g -std=gnu++14 -o mytest  main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

struct Packet {
    explicit Packet(size_t size) {
        data_.resize(size );
    }
    virtual ~Packet() {
        data_ = std::vector<char>();
        std::cout << "~Packet();\n";
    }
    std::vector<char> data_;
};

template<class T>
struct WorkerQueue {
    void Start() {
        t_ = std::move(thread{&WorkerQueue::Run, this});
    }

    void Enqueue(T t) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{m_};
        queue_.push_back(std::move(t));
        cv_.notify_one();
    }

    void Run() {
        while(true) {
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l{m_};
                cv_.wait(l, [&](){return !queue_.empty();});
                // calls T::~T()
                queue_.erase(begin(queue_));
                std::cout << "q_size: " << queue_.size() << endl;
            }
            // simulate workload
            this_thread::sleep_for(50ms);
        }
    }

    std::vector<T> queue_;
    thread t_;
    mutex m_;
    condition_variable cv_;
};


int main() {
    const size_t kPacketSize = 1*1000*1000;
    WorkerQueue<std::unique_ptr<Packet>> wq;

    wq.Start();// DOES NOT free memory
    for(int i=0;i<1000;++i) {
        wq.Enqueue(make_unique<Packet>(kPacketSize));
    }
//    wq.Start();// DOES free memory

    this_thread::sleep_for(60s);
}
```

Comment: *the memory usage of the application stays constant at 1GB until the programs exits.* -- Unless there is a legitimate memory leak, that's how your runtime's heap manager works.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie When I start this program, let it allocate 60% of my RAM, wait until it nearly finishes(so it could in theory release nearly all memory) and then start another instance of the program, my whole PC becomes unresponsive for ~5 seconds. Is it really supposed to work this way?
Thanks for your help! I'm really stuck on this since yesterday.

Comment: hmm, tried both on VS and both versions seem fine. the only thing I can think of is that "data_ = std::vector<char>();" does not free the memory as some sort of optimization. can you try replacing it with "vector<char>().swap(data_)" see if makes any difference?

Comment: @ColdSpider One program has no bearing on the other program -- they are two separate processes.   The C++ heap manager and OS are usually not in-sync with each other.  When your application calls `new[]` and then `delete[]`, it doesn't mean that a call to the OS was made to allocate memory, and then a call to the OS to deallocate the memory.  The heap manager is designed to hold onto memory in case there may be further allocations, thus speeding up the allocation process.  Calling `delete[]` will more than likely just mark that area of memory as available for further allocation requests.

Comment: @David On VS it works for me too. Using ::swap() doesn't seem to make a difference with gcc. For now I will just keep the queues reasonable small.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ah, that makes sense...
But wouldn't that imply, that every gcc-compiled program with highly volatile memory usage had to roll their own memory allocation? That seems intuitively 'wrong' to me.

Comment: Some heap managers work "better" than others (by "better" meaning that the behavior suits the particular application).  As noted by @David, the behavior is different when using Visual Studio.  I don't use gcc that often, but maybe their are compiler switches that can be used.  The bottom line is that as long as you are not leaking memory, the heap manager is "working as designed".  Whether that design fits your purposes is a different story.